# Strange behaviour from Hibernate with OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

My code is involving 3 entities:

```
@Entity
public class Data implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
               targetEntity = Bit.class,mappedBy = "data")
    private Collection<Bit> bit;    

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
               targetEntity = Linked.class,mappedBy = "data")
    private Collection<Linked> linked;
}

@Entity
public class Linked implements Serializable {
    ...
    @EmbeddedId
    private LinkIdPK id;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity = Data.class)
    private Data data;
}

@Entity
public class Bit implements Serializable {
    ...
    @EmbeddedId
    private BitIdPK id;

    @MapsId("data")@ManyToOne(optional=true,targetEntity = Data.class)
    private Data data;
```

I'm performing a search using a Spring repository in order to get one instance of Data. I know that the element I'm querying from the database has "3 Bit" elements, and "1 Linked" element in the database.

When I loop over the Bit elements in `Data.bit`, I find 3 elements, which is normal.

But when I loop over the Linked elements in `Data.linked`, I find 3 elements, which are pointing to the same object, whereas I was expecting only 1 element.

I have tried adding 1 Bit element in the database, and now I find 4 elements in `Data.linked` pointing to the same object.

Is it a normal behaviour ? Is it a bug in my code, or is it a bug in Hibernate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer from the hibernate team. It seems this is a known issue, and there is only a workaround for it, for now:
Add the annotation `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` to one of the `OneToMany` collections.

Answer (score 0):

@MapsID on the many to one mapping of Linked to Data is missing.It may be causing the issue as you are using embedded id.

Regards,

Prasad